# netty EpollEventLoopGroup vs NioEventLoopGroup, which should I choose on CentOS 6?

Tags: java, netty

I'm using netty 4.1.0CR, the official code samples suggest me to use `NioEventLoopGroup` to start a server as well as client, as following:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
```

But I'm running both server and client on Linux(CentOS 6), should I use `EpollEventLoopGroup` to get better performance? Or how could I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 9):

If you are running on linux you can use EpollEventLoopGroup and so get better performance, less GC and have more advanced features that are only available on linux.

Comment: Any references that support this opinion?

Comment: @JoseMartinez Norman Maurer happens to be one of the two main committers to the Netty Project.

Comment: @mjuarez “In God we Trust, all others bring data”  I believe the same as this post but I was trying to hunt down data to justify it.

Answer (score 2):

Netty provides the following platforms in specific JNI transports:

```
Linux (since 4.0.16)
MacOS/BSD (since 4.1.11)
```

These JNI transports add features specific to a particular platform, generate less garbage, and generally improve performance when compared to the NIO based transport.

For more information check [Netty Native transports](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Native-transports)

Comment: You have not answered the question: "Which should I choose on CentOS 6?"

Comment: Should I edit each and every fine in netty distribution to do required substitutions:
    NioEventLoopGroup → EpollEventLoopGroup
    NioEventLoop → EpollEventLoop
    NioServerSocketChannel → EpollServerSocketChannel
    NioSocketChannel → EpollSocketChannel